# Ionic and components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have several web applications developed with Angular 4 using angular-cli and I have many own components developed mixing jquery, bootstrap, material, others.

Now I want to develop something with Ionic 3. My question is: Can I use my own components with this framework or am I forced to work with Ionic components?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic components are just a collection of maintained Angular components. So you should have no issue using some of your existing Angular components.

I do not recommend adding jquery or some other heavy framework to your mobile app though as this will increase your final bundle size and will result in slow startup time, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, your opinion has been very useful. I will use my components without jquery.